# GUI disappeared in android studios

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

[image]

I have no idea what happened, considering that I have not touched the XML code at all.

[image]

I just opened Android Studios to work on the project and these errors (including the fact that for some reason I cannot seem to access the GUI anymore) have popped up. Below are screenshots of the errors. What happened, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: First try Build > Clean Project. Then Try Build > Rebuild Project.

Comment: I have tried that multiple times. I have the same problem still

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the plug-in it turns out- that solved my problem